# How do I get two modal dialogues in one page to work?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two modal dialogues in my webpage, using Twitter-bootstrap, but only one of them works.

Here is the code:

```
<a href="#format" role="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="format">Phone and Email</a>
<div id="format" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="format" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <!--This needs a fancy phone icon and so does the button.-->
    <img src="img/numberheader.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>
    <h4>Office:</h4>
    123 4567<br>
    <h4>Programme Manager:</h4>
    765 4321<br>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/emailheader.png" alt="">
    <h4>Email us</h4>Iremovedthemailaddresses<br>
    <a href="Iremovedthemailaddresses" class="btn-primary btn-small">Click Here To Email Us</a>
    <br>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal">Phone and Email</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<!--This needs a fancy phone icon and so does the button.-->
<img src="img/numberheader.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>
<h4>Office:</h4>
123 4567<br>
<h4>Programme Manager:</h4>
765 4321<br>
<hr>
<img src="img/emailheader.png" alt="">
<h4>Email us</h4>Iremovedthemailaddresses<br>
<a href="Iremovedthemailaddresses" class="btn-primary btn-small">Click Here To Email Us</a>
<br>
</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The content of the two modals has not been separated into what it's meant to be yet, it's just proof of concept at this point (so ignore the content).

However, it only works for the second one, not the first. What can I do to make both modals work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your anchor tags and modal id are unique.

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2UR/**

Comment: I think I see what I did wrong, I think I left out the data-toogle.